# How to redraw views in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a listView inside a fragment. Some text parts of views inside the listview are downloaded from the web in the adapter. When I change this text parts from another fragent I want the first fragment to redraw it's views.

I tried:

```
myListView.invalidate();
myListView.invalidateViews();
myListView.refreshDrawableState();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.updateComments();
```

UpdateComments is my own function. I save pointers to current shown views in onScroll and ask every view to update the requested views, but nothing happens.

If I scroll down and then up and my view redraws with getView method of the adapter new text is shown.

How to update the views without scrolling?

Comment: you may want to use asynctask and see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882475/android-how-to-update-arrayadapter-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ok with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

but it scrolls to the top of the listview so I then use

```
feed.setSelection(adapter.lastPosition);
```

I obtain lastPosition in the onScroll method of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

use setAdapter or setListAdapter once again on the list after update.

Comment: I dont want to reload all the data again.